# What does "géométrie de situation" mean?

Tags: translation-request, mathematical-french

What does the mathematical French phrase

*géométrie de situation*

mean?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Initially with Chasles it meant Enumerative Geometry. Later on with Poincare and Hadamard it meant Analysis Situs or, in modern language, Topology.

Answer (score 0):

*Geometry of situation* - Being situated means being placed or located. You can even see this in the English *to sit*, or *site*. Now, what is the Greek equivalent of place, site, or location ? ;-)